# Group total in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My SQL query returns:

```
orderhed_pino_c OrderHed_OrderNum   OrderDtl_OrderLine  calculated_totalsqm
19.0503 50291   1   1.6359
19.0503 50291   1   1.6359
19.0503 50291   2   1.59244
19.0503 50291   2   1.59244
19.0503 50292   1   28.0476
19.0503 50290   1   3.2718
19.0503 50288   1   7.418808
19.0503 50288   1   7.418808
19.0503 50288   1   7.418808
19.0503 50290   3   1
19.0503 50288   1   7.418808
19.0503 50288   1   7.418808
19.0503 50288   1   7.418808
19.0503 50290   4   38.868
19.0503 50288   1   7.418808
19.0503 50288   1   7.418808
19.0503 50288   1   7.418808
```

In SSRS I have grouped by `OrderHed_OrderNum` and `OrderDtl_OrderLine` 
Please see the image.

[image: Query output]

I want to have total `calculate_totalsqm` for `orderhed_ordernum` .

but I am getting the total of all rows.

For `orderhed_ordernum = 50291` I have two `orderdtl_orderline` 1 and 2 so total should be 1.6359 + 1.59244 = 3.22834

[image: result set]

but SSRS is showing 6.45.

I have dataset query as:

```sql
SELECT Sum(t1)
FROM (
  SELECT [orderhed_ordernum] AS T2
    , Avg([calculated_totalsqm]) AS T1
    , [orderdtl_orderline] AS T3
  FROM dbo.[baqreportresult_" + parameters!tableguid.value + "]
  GROUP BY [orderhed_ordernum], [orderdtl_orderline]
) BB
GROUP  BY t2
```

but I am getting error as:

> Program Ice.Services.Lib.RunTask raised an unexpected exception with the following message: RunTask: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset 'TotalSQM'. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'By'.****

Comment: Please format your question so that its readable https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: In a query don't you reference parameters as `@tableguid`?

Comment: But I don't think you can create dynamic SQL using parameters

Comment: Please help,What would be good way to achieve this?

Comment: I have no idea - its not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve... how many different tables have you got?

Comment: From the data and error message you provided, I can tell a couple things. One, the error is related to one of your group by clauses.  Try commenting them out one by one to determine which is the issue.  Second, your data seems to be returned duplicate records and then it is summing all of those records.  You could probably slap a `SELECT DISTINCT` in there and it should sum the correct records.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use parameter values to alter the text of your Sql statement (i.e. to provide database, table or field names), then turn the whole Sql statement into an expression. Right-click the dataset, click Properties and click the `fx` button beside the Sql statement to edit it and turn it into a string expression. Enter the following:

```
="SELECT Sum(t1) "
&"FROM ( "
&"  SELECT [orderhed_ordernum] AS T2 "
&"    , Avg([calculated_totalsqm]) AS T1 "
&"    , [orderdtl_orderline] AS T3 "
&"  FROM dbo.[baqreportresult_" & Parameters!tableguid.value & "] "
&"  GROUP BY [orderhed_ordernum], [orderdtl_orderline] "
&") BB "
&"GROUP BY t2 "
```

So this just encapsulates the entire Sql in quotes, turning it into a string expression, and inserts the parameter value into the Sql statement to calculate the right table name at run time. The Sql statement is built from the string expression at run time, creating your desired table name from your tableguid parameter and then executing that against the database.

Note the spaces at the end of each line which are needed as this will result in one line of Sql.

Note also that string concatentation uses `&` rather than `+`.